# If ScrollView only supports one direct child, How to display the whole layout scrollable?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Here i am showing the xml layout of my application.i want to scroll the whole pages using  Scrollview .But i am unable to use.ScrollView only supports one direct child.But i wanna to scroll the whole content.please help me to solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/left_white" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="185dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:hint="" 
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tour"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

            </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What interests you?"
        android:textSize="20dp" >

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <com.android.example.CoverFlow
                    android:id="@+id/coverFlow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dip"/>

            </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    >

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put Scroll view before your main LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
       <LinearLayout>
             // This Linear Layout contains your entire layout code
       </LinearLayout>
    </Scrollview>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if i put scrollview in main layout,the layout couldnt display.

Comment: @rajeshlawrance I edit my answer please check it and show me your code please.

Comment: Ya but where is the scrollview ?

Comment: if i put scrollview before my main linearLayout i got the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Check my answer again and apply like that

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
<your main layout>    
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>

 your whole layout code here
</LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
</your main layout>
```

Comment: i think i have mentioned clearly that you have to add your scrollview after your main layout

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. It supports only one child. But if you want the above xml file to be scrollable, Put your main Linearlayout inside scrollView tag. The main LinearLayout will be considered as single child of ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i changed.but not yet come.i didnt get the scrollview

Comment: The problem is here that, even if you able to use ScrollView for the parent layout, as you are using a List inside the linearlayout, you shouldn't or can't use ScrollView, since, both ScrollView and list have scrolling capability, you should not inflate a list inside ScrollView. Since you are using a list, you don't need to use the ScrollView here.\

Comment: ya.because i am using listview inside my linearlayout.my list is scrolling.but also i want to scroll whole page.so that i can see the whole content using scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- add your entire layout here -->



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/prev"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/left_white" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:hint="" 
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/tour"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="What interests you?"
            android:textSize="20dp" >

    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >

                    <com.android.example.CoverFlow
                        android:id="@+id/coverFlow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"/>

                </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: i got the error in line starts with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ListView inside ScrollView. Many of us got this problem. So here is the solution of this question:

1. Create a **list.xml** that contains just ListView
2. Create a **header.xml** that contains above the XML code of ListView
3. Create a **footer.xml** that contains below the XML code of ListView

At last, from your main class grab the ListView reference and add list Header and Footer. Hope this will work. If you have any problem with this make sure your comment.